# How to open and read a *.xls file through creating a browse button

Tags: excel, vba, button

I've googled almost a day now and can't really find what I'm looking for!

I've created a button on my excel sheet. I want this button to open a .xls file from the browser dialog. I've managed to find the program code below, but it opens my .xls in a new workbook.

I want the .xls file to open in a specific cell in the same sheet as the button. For instance I have my button placed in cell B8 in my sheet1. I want to open the .xls file exactly under it - in cell B9 in same sheet1

Also one more thing, when I press the button and press "Cancel" I dont want it to print "FALSE".

Here is the code that i've found:

```
Sub Knapp1_Klicka()

    objFile = Application.GetOpenFilename(fileFilter:="All Files (* . *) , * . * ")   

    Set curSheet = ActiveSheet
    Set mWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(objFile)
    curSheet.Activate

    Call someFunction(curSheet, mWorkbook)
End Sub

Sub someFunction(targetSheet, srcWorkbook)

    numSheets = srcWorkbook.Sheets.Count
    For i = 1 To numSheets
        targetSheet.Cells(i, 1) = srcWorkbook.Sheets(i).Name
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: `Also one more thing, when I press the button and press "Cancel" I dont want it to print "FALSE".` The answer lies in the inbuilt Excel help :) Search for `.GetOpenFilename` in the inbuilt Excel help.

Comment: `I want the .xls file to open in a specific cell in the same sheet as the button.` Excel file doesn't open in a `cell`. It opens in the Excel Application from where you will have to read the necessary data from the necessary sheet and then put that data in the relevant cell.

Comment: Do you wish to **copy** the data from the newly-opened worksheet onto the sheet with the button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To handle the cancel event, you need to check the result of `Application.GetOpenFileName` is a valid filename.  You can do this with the `Dir` function.

Also it is helpful to always declare your variables.

```
Sub TryMe()
    Dim objFile as String
    Dim curSheet as Worksheet
    Dim mWorkbook as Workbook
    objFile = Application.GetOpenFilename(fileFilter:="All Files (* . *) , * . * ")   

    If Len(Dir(objFile)) = 0 Then Exit Sub 'handles the "Cancel" event
    Set curSheet = ActiveSheet
    Set mWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(objFile)

    'Copy the values from the activesheet in this workbook:
    ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Copy Destination:=curSheet.Range("B9")
End Sub
```

Note that this approach may fail if you are using a very large range in the workbook, since it cannot potentially copy the entire worksheet and paste to Range `B9`, but the likelihood of this happening seems pretty low (basically it would happen if the `mWorkbook` sheet was completely full of data in all columns and rows).

Comment: `If Len(Dir(objFile)) = 0 Then Exit Sub` not required :) If you check the excel's inbuilt help as I suggested in the comment above, it suggests a simple way to handle it :)

Comment: @SiddharthRout +1. I'm so used to simply passing strings to the `Workbooks.Open` method (instead of using the `.GetOpenFileName` which is a manual step) that I forget about that way to check.  When passing strings, I have to check if the string is valid filename :)